# Need help looking for a module that can create color swatches by linking multiple simple-typed products

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I’m in searching for a module that would allow me to create color swatches for products such as t-shirts or bags that actually link between multiple simple products instead of using a bundled product.

I did some online and found couple of the modules such as 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-color-swatch.html 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/color-swatches-magento-extension.html

However, they all seem to simply extend the functionality of a bundle product.

Is there any module out there (for version 1.7.0.2) that allows a merchant to link up multiple products (same product type but have different colors and SKU) just like this website? http://www.knomobags.com/usa/laptop-sleeves/alfie-slim-briefcase-marine.html/ (check "More Colours" option)

I’m hoping to reduce the development type by using a 3rd party module instead of implementing the custom code myself.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea.Make an attribute called colour. There you can save there links of your different products by output an image or a link with the colour name.I think we have did something similar with different book format: 
[The History Press](http://www.thehistorypress.co.uk/index.php/history-ebooks/french-eagles-soviet-heroes-ebook.html)
Each book is a different product with unique sku.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. In that case, do we need to maintain the links to different products on each products? For example, we have products A,B,and C. Will I need to link up B,C to A; and A,C to B; and A,B to C?

Comment: Yes exactly.That's a solution if you want don't want to  make them bundle.